# Adding custom header is overriding old header entries. How to preserve old header entries in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, httpinterceptor

I am trying to add few custom header entries, but after adding these values I am no longer seeing old header entries.

```js
@Injectable()
export class fwcAPIInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const authReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers
                .set('test1', 'test1')
                .set('test2', 'test2')
        });
        return next.handle(authReq);
    }
```

Comment: Where are you checking them?

Comment: In the Chrome developer tool. Header entries I was seeing before after making these changes.

Comment: Do you mean in network tab? Or by logging it in console?

Comment: Yes in network tab

Answer (score 0):

Angular `HttpRequest` supports adding headers using `setHeaders` parameter so you don't have to override the whole headers object. It is the recommended way to set headers in an interceptor.

```
@Injectable()
export class fwcAPIInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const authReq = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                test1: 'test1',
                test2: 'test2'
            }
        });
        return next.handle(authReq);
    }    
}
```

Comment: I am getting same result in Chrome. I see "Provisional headers are shown" in Chrome debugger. It works in IE though.